how to apply ros2_control on urdf model?
I have designed a robot model using fusion 360 and exported the urdf, but how can I put ros2_contorl in the code below and control it in the gazebo? Also, how can I attach the base link of the robot to the floor when I am doing real time in the gazebo? Can you provide a tutorial for this?
Also, the video I found is below, would it be possible to do my robot model like the ROS version?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRCjPeG95CQ&list=PLJOHOcnvyOr3kBviehO2aE8sVXpGtTzZq
code (how to put the ros2 control plugin in this code?)
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="ArmBot" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

<xacro:include filename="$(find ArmBot_description)/urdf/materials.xacro" />
<xacro:include filename="$(find ArmBot_description)/urdf/ArmBot.trans" />
<xacro:include filename="$(find ArmBot_description)/urdf/ArmBot.gazebo" />
<link name="base_link">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="-5.790023100122029e-18 2.8950115500610146e-18 0.012499999999999997" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="0.385335973916873"/>
    <inertia ixx="8e-05" iyy="8e-05" izz="0.00012" ixy="-0.0" iyz="-0.0" ixz="-0.0"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ArmBot_description)/meshes/base_link.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ArmBot_description)/meshes/base_link.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="limb1_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="-0.012677333119733436 5.334469225559074e-18 0.02130554554064787" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="0.8364859167606822"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.000263" iyy="0.000353" izz="0.000352" ixy="0.0" iyz="0.0" ixz="5.2e-05"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="-0.0 -0.0 -0.025" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ArmBot_description)/meshes/limb1_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
</geometry>
<material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
<origin xyz="-0.0 -0.0 -0.025" rpy="0 0 0"/>
<geometry>
  <mesh filename="file://$(find ArmBot_description)/meshes/limb1_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="limb2_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="-0.02467452355398319 4.312937701496405e-18 0.0172437368796389" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="1.0346099780261684"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.000531" iyy="0.000563" izz="0.000354" ixy="0.0" iyz="0.0" ixz="0.000102"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.04 -0.0 -0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ArmBot_description)/meshes/limb2_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
</geometry>
<material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
<origin xyz="0.04 -0.0 -0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
<geometry>
  <mesh filename="file://$(find ArmBot_description)/meshes/limb2_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="limb3_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="0.016572750410208385 3.97492501969871e-18 0.029605864866220216" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="1.1225893214236413"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.000464" iyy="0.000679" izz="0.000566" ixy="0.0" iyz="-0.0" ixz="-0.000172"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.07 -0.0 -0.1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ArmBot_description)/meshes/limb3_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
</geometry>
<material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
<origin xyz="0.07 -0.0 -0.1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
<geometry>
  <mesh filename="file://$(find ArmBot_description)/meshes/limb3_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="limb4_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="0.030579701765970288 -1.1006970168880519e-17 0.01845016001490593" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="1.216195277749335"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.000688" iyy="0.000811" izz="0.000504" ixy="-0.0" iyz="0.0" ixz="-0.000199"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.02 -0.0 -0.14" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find ArmBot_description)/meshes/limb4_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
</geometry>
<material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
<origin xyz="0.02 -0.0 -0.14" rpy="0 0 0"/>
<geometry>
  <mesh filename="file://$(find ArmBot_description)/meshes/limb4_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<joint name="limb1_to_base_link" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.025" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="limb1_1"/>
  <axis xyz="0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="limb2_to_limb1" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="-0.04 0.0 0.025" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="limb1_1"/>
  <child link="limb2_1"/>
  <axis xyz="-1.0 0.0 0.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="limb3_to_limb2" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="-0.03 0.0 0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="limb2_1"/>
  <child link="limb3_1"/>
  <axis xyz="0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="limb4_to_limb3" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="0.05 0.0 0.04" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="limb3_1"/>
  <child link="limb4_1"/>
  <axis xyz="1.0 0.0 0.0"/>
</joint>

</robot>

In the config folder, we have created a yaml file for each joint.

If I get your question correctly, I think you could add something like this in your URDF file:
<gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros2_control" filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so">
      <robotNamespace>/your_robot_name</robotNamespace>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

This is how i found to do it in one of my projects, make sure to install the library first.

Have you had a look into the ros2_control_demos or gazebo_ros2_control_demos?
